# Storyboard initialization and deinit

Tags: swift, macos

When initializing a ViewController via a Storyboard (NS or UI), do you need to keep a reference to the storyboard or can you just ignore it when you are done with it and let it deinit?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var secondarySB: NSStoryboard? = nil

    @IBAction
    func loadAndKeep(_ sender: NSButton) {
        //keeping a reference
        secondarySB = NSStoryboard.init(name: NSStoryboard.Name.init(rawValue: "Secondary"), bundle: nil)
        let vc = secondarySB?.instantiateInitialController() as! Secondary
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
    }
    @IBAction
    func load(_ sender: NSButton) {
        //ignoring the storyboard after I get the viewcontroller
        let sb = NSStoryboard.init(name: NSStoryboard.Name.init(rawValue: "Secondary"), bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateInitialController() as! Secondary
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you are force casting using "as!"; this is typically not recommended you should instead use "as?" and then "vc?.view" in case something went wrong.  There is a nice tool that you can use called SwiftLint that will catch that kind of stuff and generate build warnings were appropriate.

Comment: it can be deinit no need to keep reference of storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to keep a reference to the storyboard, but you do need to add the instantiated view controller as a child view controller.